# Getting prompted for password when going to My Sites

Tags: 2010, my-site, my-profile, login

I have created a web app for hosting my sites and configured it according to Microsoft best practice on technet. However, when I log on to the portal I enter my credentials and when I click on my name on the upper right hand corner and go My Profile I get prompted for password again before I get redirected to my profile. I don't think it should be like this but not sure where to start looking really, any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to authenticate to each web application you visit.  If your main site is http://intranet and your MySite host and personal sites are at http://mysites then going to the user profile (within the MySite Host) or to a personal site would require authentication again.

If you are using Windows Auth, then it would be a good idea to configure the user's browsers to pass the user's logged in credentials to avoid log in prompts in most scenarios.

Comment: We're using Windows Auth so is there a way in IIS/AD or something to configure this? We have a couple of thousand users using all sorts of clients (PC/Mac/iPad/iPhone) and browsers. We had the three login prompt issue but sorted it with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us. Microsoft recommends to create a new web app for hosting my sites which I did but was it really a good idea if the users have to authenticate a second time?

Comment: A separate web app is almost always the preferred method.  How are your sites addressed?  Host Headers, server names, IPs?  Integrated login will only work for IE users, other browsers, non-domain computers, or mobile devices will require authentication.

Comment: http://portal with alternate access mapping http://portal.company.com for external access, my sites internal url at http://portal:SomePort with alternate access mapping for external use http://my.company.com, would claims authentication solve this issue with shared authentication? If this double login prompt is a big issue for the client would you recommend to keep My Sites in the same web app as the portal?

Comment: You should avoid using ports for production systems.  Using host headers like internal.company.com and external.company.com is better, and also part of what is pointed out in your kb article.  My recommendation would be to set it up using host headers for both web applications.  If that isn't possible, then you could move it all to the main web app, but that leads to a number of other issues and limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this article, which helps you in fixing the issue..
[SharePoint site continually prompting for passwords](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharepoint-site-continuously-prompting.html)
Hope this helps you!

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.